# Do Varnas have subcategories?

Tags: scripture, tradition, caste-system, varna

- Present **Caste System** is a **modified Varna Dharma** by Britishers.
- There are **many subcategories** even for a **single Caste**. (more than 7 in some cases)
- I didn't see any scriptures mentioning subcategories in any Varna.

**MY QUESTION :**

- Do/did Varnas also have subcategories like Caste or Jati ?

Comment: What do you mean by this "Present Caste System is an Alternate of Varna by Britisher's"??

Comment: @Yogi friend Varna with 4 divisons  were modified with caste like Brahmin,Harijan,Dalit, etc,... to even 300 or 400 castes

Comment: @@Sakthi No sub categories afaik.

Comment: sub categories arose over time. there is no mention of sub-categories in vedas. Not due to British, just over long period of time.

Comment: @ Swami Vishwanada Do vedas support birth based caste system?